# Android OS blocks my network packages

Tags: android, google-maps, timer, threadpool

My App sends out GPS data with a timer. Sometimes I block the screen.

Now with some phones and only sometimes I have the problem that the OS somehow blocks the data packages and only releases them later, when the screen is unlocked. The messages still are getting sent from the app but only stopped in android.

Anybody have a Idea why that happens and how I can stop it?

Comment: May be your WiFi going to sleep? Try settings/wireless/wifi settings then press the menu button and select advanced/wifi sleep policy. Change from when screen is off to never.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that those devices are going to sleep (or sending the radio to sleep)?  Have you tried setting a wakelock to prevent this?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your application goes to sleep, or your wifi.  There are applications specifically designed to keep your wifi alive, so i suspect it does sleep.   Were i to create the wifi, i would definitely make it sleep when there wasnt anything to say.

To test download one of the apps.  That and write to a log file when your application is going to sleep.

Sorry i couldnt give a specific answer.   Id have posted this as a comment, but im too new to be able to do that.